# Tab traversal behavior on Mac - for the demo project

Tags: macos, wxpython

Tabs do not traverse between button controls, using the demo project, but only on a Mac.

I have downloaded the demo tarball from [wx Python demo site](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html) -- and ran in on a Mac and windows 10.  On a Mac, you can't tab between the buttons on the page, and on windows it works just fine.  This is the same behavior I have an in app I wrote, and was sort of glad to find it happens on code that I have not written.

Is this a known limitation of wxPython on a Mac or is there anything else I can do to make this work on a Mac?  I need to have tabs working as one of the accessibility requirements.

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/26/use-the-tab-key-to-switch-between-dialog-buttons-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: A duh moment for me.  thank you.